# NestJS Bull Queues: How to skip processing in test env?

Tags: testing, jestjs, queue, nestjs, bull

I'm using [NestJS Queues via Bull](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues) and writing unit tests in Jest. I want to skip the processing of jobs triggered during testing.

There's a GH issue on [test mode for Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/962) but they won't implement it.

Preferably I'd avoid extensive mocking, a simple option on `BullModule` would be best.

Answer (score 7):

I also had a hard time with this, so I'm posting my solution. I'm just simplifying my code for this purpose, so use with caution, there might be some typos etc.

```js
describe('JobCreatorService', () => {
  let service: JobCreatorService;
  let moduleRef: TestingModule;

  const exampleQueueMock = { add: jest.fn() };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        BullModule.registerQueue({
          name: EXAMPLE_QUEUE,
        }),
      ],
    })
      .overrideProvider(getQueueToken(EXAMPLE_QUEUE))
      .useValue(exampleQueueMock)
      .compile();

    service = moduleRef.get<JobCreatorService>(JobCreatorService);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await moduleRef.close();
  });

  it('should dispatch job', async () => {
    await service.methodThatDispatches();
    expect(exampleQueueMock.add).toHaveBeenCalledWith({example: jobData});
  });
});
```

I don't recommend unit tests having side effects - like storing data in the DB or redis, that's why this approach. However if you prefer to actually store the jobs in redis, you might find some inspiration here: https://github.com/nestjs/bull/blob/master/e2e/module.e2e-spec.ts

Comment: Using the Queue Mock should be documentented in NestJS / Bull...

Answer (score 0):

Currently, my workaround is to delay test jobs by an arbitrary high timeframe. I can Initialize `BullModule` when building my test module as follows:

```js
moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    BullModule.forRoot({
      redis: process.env.REDIS_URL,
      defaultJobOptions: {
        delay: 99999999999999999,
      },
    }),
    // ...,
  ],
}).compile();
```

I don't like this so much as the jobs will idle in Redis.